# Sanity wont let me login through terminal/console

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I was logging into my sanity account through terminal or console but it didn't seem to work since it was aborting the process automatically!
Anyone here know how to fix this thing?

```bash
C:\Users\Realtrickz\OneDrive\Desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce>sanity login
? Login type Google

Opening browser at https://api.sanity.io/v1/auth/login/google?type=listen&uuid=___________________&source=cli&label=________

- Waiting for browser login to complete... Press Ctrl + C to cancelnode:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn undefined\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn undefined\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell',
  path: 'undefined\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell',
  spawnargs: [
    '-NoProfile',
    '-NonInteractive',
    '–ExecutionPolicy',
    'Bypass',
    '-EncodedCommand',
    'UwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAIgBoAHQAdABwAHMAOgAvAC8AYQBwAGkALgBzAGEAbgBpAHQAeQAuAGkAbwAvAHYAMQAvAGEAdQB0AGgALwBsAG8AZwBpAG4ALwBnAG8AbwBnAGwAZQA/AHQAeQBwAGUAPQBsAGkAcwB0AGUAbgAmAHUAdQBpAGQAPQAwAGQAZQBiAGYAOABiADcAYQBjAGMAZgBlAGIAZgBmADIAZgAzADQAYwAzADkAMQA4AGQAMgBlADEAZQA2ADUAJgBzAG8AdQByAGMAZQA9AGMAbABpACYAbABhAGIAZQBsAD0ARABFAFMASwBUAE8AUAAtAEkAVAA1ADcATwBDAE4AKwAlADIARgArAHcAaQBuADMAMgAiAA=='
  ]
}

Node.js v18.14.0

C:\Users\Realtrickz\OneDrive\Desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce>
```

Answer (score 1):

install sanity cli by run
sudo npm install --global sanity@latest
then run sanity login
on Windows no need for sudo

Answer (score 0):

The only fix that worked for me was to download Git Bash and run Sanity login there. Once logged in, you can use VScode terminal or CMD and run Sanity create... in the project folder you want to use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the git bash terminal, if you use the powershell one it always will throw the same error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).